# Solving unclassifiable error

Tags: fortran

I was working on my analysis code's input part, but I've got stuck because of multiple errors. Here is my unfinished code:

```
    c     sinle event analysis

      implicit real(a-h,o-z)
      real day(12), nmonth(12), year(12), clas(12),
     $ hour(12), nmin(12), sec(12)
      real mark(12)
      real tst(12)
      dimension  D(12)

      real time(2054904), proa(2054904), w1(2054904),
     $ w2(2054904), w3(2054904), w4(2054904) 

      D(1) = 31, D(2) = 28, D(3) = 31, D(4) = 30, D(5) = 31,
     $ D(6) = 30, D(7) = 31, D(8) = 31, D(9) = 30, D(10) = 31,
     $ D(11) = 30, D(12) = 31

      open(100,file='singleE.txt',status='OLD')

      do i=1, 12
       tst(i)=0
      enddo

900   do i=1, 12
       read(100, 1150) day(i), nmonth(i), year(i),
     $  hour(i), nmin(i), sec(i), clas(i)

       do j=12, 1, -1

        if integer(nmonth(i)) == j then         
         tst(i) = tst(i) + D(j-1)
        endif

       enddo

       tst(i) = tst(i) + day(i) + (year(i) - 2010)*365
     $  + (hour(i) + nmin(i)/60)/24 

       if year(i) > 2011 then tst(i) = tst(i) + 1/365
       endif

       print *, day(i), nmonth(i), year(i), hour(i), nmin(i),
     $  sec(i), clas(i), tst(i)

      enddo

      open(200,file='hole.dat',status='OLD')



950   FORMAT(F12.7,2x,E10.3,2x,E10.3,2x,E10.3,2x,E10.3,
     $ 2x,E10.3,2x,E10.3)

1150  FORMAT(F2.0,1x,F2.0,1x,F4.0,1x,F2.0,1x,F2.0,4x, 
     $ F3.1)

      end
```

The code is breaking up, I don't know why :( 
Anyways, And here is the errors I've got:

singleA.f:13.6:

```
  D(1) = 31, D(2) = 28, D(3) = 31, D(4) = 30, D(5) = 31,            
  1
```

Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
singleA.f:29.8:

```
    if integer(nmonth(i)) == j then                                 
    1
```

Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
singleA.f:31.11:

```
    endif                                                           
       1
```

Error: Expecting END DO statement at (1)
singleA.f:38.7:

```
   if year(i) > 2011 then tst(i) = tst(i) + 1/365                   
   1
```

Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
singleA.f:39.10:

```
   endif                                                            
      1
```

Error: Expecting END DO statement at (1)

The main problem are the first and the second ones. The rest of them are, I think, caused by the second error. I know this is a long code, but It would be nice if somebody enlighten me of my mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

This, and the lines like it

```
D(1) = 31, D(2) = 28, D(3) = 31, D(4) = 30, D(5) = 31,
```

is just not syntactically correct; in fact it's so broken the compiler can't figure out what's wrong and marks it as 'unclassifiable'.

The easy fix would be to put every statement on a separate line and lose the commas.  Or you could replace `,` with `;` which is the Fortran statement separator character.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know I am not supposed to use comma there.